# Need help in promtool test - its failing for one alert or the other

Tags: prometheus

I have below prometheus unit test

I tried a lot of manipulations on input_series. But it is always throwing failure.
It only evaluates the first value in the input series.

```
Unit Testing:  tests/infra_db_alerts-tests.yml
  FAILED:
    alertname: MySQLReplicationDown, time: 10m,
        exp:[
            0:
              Labels:{alert_owner="alerts-infra", alertname="MySQLReplicationDown", severity="High"}
              Annotations:{description="MySQL replication is broken. \n"}
            ],
        got:[]
```

Prometheus test rule

```
rule_files:
  - ../rules/db_alerts.yml

tests:
  # MySQL Alert Tests
  - input_series:
      - series: mysql_up
        values: 0
      - series: mysql_global_variables_innodb_replication_delay
        values: '1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1'

    alert_rule_test:
      - alertname: MySQLReplicationLag
        eval_time: 5m
        exp_alerts:
          - exp_labels:
              severity: High
              alert_owner: alerts-infra
            exp_annotations:
              description: "There is a MySQL replication delay. \n"

      - alertname: MySQLReplicationDown
        eval_time: 10m
        exp_alerts:
          - exp_labels:
              severity: High
              alert_owner: alerts-infra
            exp_annotations:
              description: "MySQL replication is broken. \n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by creating two alert test rules with its own input series.

```
rule_files:
  - ../rules/db_alerts.yml

tests:
  # MySQL Alert Tests
  - input_series:
      - series: mysql_up
        values: 0
      - series: mysql_global_variables_innodb_replication_delay
        values: 1

    alert_rule_test:
      - alertname: MySQLReplicationLag
        eval_time: 5m
        exp_alerts:
          - exp_labels:
              severity: High
              alert_owner: alerts-infra
            exp_annotations:
              description: "There is a MySQL replication delay. \n"

  - input_series:
      - series: mysql_global_variables_innodb_replication_delay
        values: -1  
    alert_rule_test:
    - alertname: MySQLReplicationDown
        eval_time: 10m
        exp_alerts:
          - exp_labels:
              severity: High
              alert_owner: alerts-infra
            exp_annotations:
              description: "MySQL replication is broken. \n"
```